# How safe is fresh Centos 6 Standard Server Installation?

Tags: linux, wordpress, webserver, centos6

Is installing Centos using standard installation for webserver relative safe? (without considering the CMS safety and only for Wordpress). The contents are:
- Virtualmin & Webmin:
- APC caching
- Apache, MySQL and Php
Everything is installed with default settings.
I installed Centos server at home and access it 100% from local network.
If it is not safe then what is the minimum requirement for safety?

Comment: all nix oses are the same in the end. centos like debain (i use) like *bsd run on the same methodology (though ports are necessary for certain indepth operations). you are talking about out-of-the-box features. any nix os can be designed to run exactly the same as another, so if you use centos, i can make debian or freebsd have the exact same functionality as centos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Safe' is too relative a term really.  CentOS 6, Virtualmin and Webmin all have security bugs filed against them, some of which can even be exploited automatically by scripts and packages like Metasploit.

That said, no system will ever be perfectly secure unless you bury it underground with no net connection, so here are some good initial steps to take to improve security a little:

- Turn off services and daemons that you don't need.  For instance, it could be that you won't be using FTP, and will use SFTP for file transfer.  If so, turn off the ones you aren't using.
- Enforce a policy of unique and secure passwords of a decent length
- install system updates, especially security updates.
- Modify IPtables settings to disallow access to unused ports.  Look into further iptables settings that can help
- Consider key-based logins, 2 or 3 factor authentication etc. and weigh the pros and cons (google authenticator PAM module is very easy to install, for example).

That's a good start off, a key thing is to keep an eye on the server, try to monitor if unusual bandwidth, or logins are being used.

No box is a fortress, but you can at the very least discourage opportunists.